# using if statement in Makefile.am(automake)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, automake

I know that for Makefile we can write the following bloc

```
ifneq ($(MYAPP_REVISION)_,_)
ifneq ($(MYAPP_REVISION),exported)
    myapp_CFLAGS+=-DMYAPP_REVISION=\"$(MYAPP_REVISION)\"
    myapp_LDFLAGS+=-DMYAPP_REVISION=\"$(MYAPP_REVISION)\"
endif
endif
```

But if write this bloc in the `makefile.am` (autoconf) I will get the build not working.

Any idea about writing the equivalent of this bloc in the `makefile.am`?

Comment: Have you tried the manual?  http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals see also http://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_179.html

Comment: You can write that sort of thing in a Makefile, but not all versions of make will recognize it.  One of the points of automake is that it produces (mostly) portable makefiles.  Writing non-portable syntax into a Makefile.am is counter-productive.

Answer (score 1):

You must look for generated output and quote M4 syntax in your source peace.